# How to define default value for parameter of a struct, when parameter is a sum of rows of an array function?

Tags: rust, closures

I'm trying to assign default value to a parameter of a structure. Note: parameter is a function, which takes 2d array and finds sum for each row, returning a `Vec<f32>` array.

Code for searching sum of each row is known:

```
let arr_2d:Vec<Vec<f32>> = vec![some values];
let vec_of_sums = arr_2d.iter()
                       .map(|row| row.iter().sum())
                       .collect::Vec<f32>();
```

But how can I use it to assign default value?
My idea was to use closures:

```
#[derive(Derivative)]
#[derivative(Debug, Default)]

struct SomeAlgorithm {
    #[derivative(Default(value = "10"))]
    n: usize,
    #[derivative(Default(value = "2"))]
    m: usize,
    #[derivative(Default(value = "|x| x.iter()
                       .map(|row| row.iter().sum())
                       .collect::Vec<u64>()"  ))]
    score_function: fn(Vec<Vec<f32>>),
}
```

However, it's not working

Comment: What do you mean by "assign default value" Do you want to implement `Default` for `SomeAlgorithm`?

Comment: Closures cannot be coerced into function pointers. Define a free-standing function that performs this computation and store a pointer to it in the default impl.

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze I don't need that since I'm using ```Derivative``` crate: I can assign default value using row on the top of param's row. I will update the question to make it more clearer.

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze's comment still stands: you specify `score_function` to be a function pointer, but you specify your default value to be a closure. This is not valid as closures cannot be coerced into function pointers.

Comment: @HeikoRibberink well, I don't need to necessarily use closures. Perhaps I can do it some other way? Or in case of using function as a parameter, I **have to** define my own ```Default```?

Comment: As @AleksanderKrauze proposed, you could define a freestanding function and pass the function name as the default value: `#[derivative(Default(value = "mydefaultfunction"))]`